# ExtJS Using a Combobox in a popup window

Tags: forms, extjs, combobox, popup, window

I'm trying to add a combobox to a floating (popup) form panel in ExtJS. But I'm getting a "Cannot set property 'component' of null" error and the window will not load.

I use the following code in a controller to create the window:

```
onTreeAddDocClick: function () {
    var f = new Ext.form.Panel({
        frame: false,
        header: false,
        floating: true,
        closable: true,
        items: [{
            xtype: 'addDoc'
        }]
    });
    f.show();
}
```

The code for the window itself is as follows:

```
Ext.define('OPENhrm.view.dossier.widget.popup.AddDoc', {
extend: 'Ext.form.Panel',
xtype: 'addDoc',

requires: [
    'Ext.layout.container.VBox'
],

controller: "dossier-addDoc",

viewModel: {
    type: "dossier-addDoc"
},

id: 'addDocForm',

frame: true,
title: 'Add document',
width: 400,
bodyPadding: '10 10 0',
layout: 'form',
closable: true,

defaults: {
    anchor: '100%',
    allowBlank: false,
    msgTarget: 'side',
    labelWidth: 50
},

items: [{
    // item selector 
    xtype: 'filefield',
    emptyText: 'Select Document',
    fieldLabel: 'Document',
    name: 'filePath',
    id: 'filePath',
    buttonText: 'upload document',

    buttonConfig: {
        icon : '/resources/images/icons/add.jpg'
    }
}, {
    xtype: 'combo',
    fieldLabel: 'Test',
    hiddenName: 'test',
    store: new Ext.data.SimpleStore({
        data: [
            ['Test1'],
            ['Test2']
        ],
        id: 0,
        fields: ['text']
    }),
    valueField: 'text',
    displayField: 'text',
    triggerAction: 'all',
    editable: false
}],

// buttons
buttons: [{
    text: 'Add',
    handler: 'onAddDockClick'
}, {
    text: 'Reset',
    handler: function () {
        this.up('form').getForm().reset();
    }
}]
});
```

If I remove the combobox, the window works just fine. If I place the combobox in a form somewhere else in my application (e.g. on a page with 2 panels; a searchfilter/form and a grid with search results), it works just fine. That other page however, is not a floating/popup window.

I got it to work by defining the whole page in the controller, but as I'm using a MVC structure, that doesn't seem like the way to go. Does anyone know how to get the combobox to work in a floating window, without putting the whole code for that window in the controller?

Comment: Why are you using `Ext.form.Panel` for your floating "window" instead of `Ext.window.Window` or simply `Ext.panel.Panel`? Look, you are nesting form panels in your code.

Comment: Do you mean I should `extend: 'Ext.window.Window'` in the xtype addDoc? Can you explain why? I don't know where the nesting is that you're referring to.

Comment: Your 'addDoc' xtype currently derives from `Ext.form.Panel`. The floating so-called "window" is an instance of `Ext.form.Panel` too (the one created in your `onTreeAddDocClick` handler). It adds an `xtype: addDoc' ` item as its child.

Comment: just change `new Ext.form.Panel` to `new Ext.window.Window`

Comment: I tried changing it to `panel.Panel` and `window.Window` but no luck. I'm getting this error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'component' of null` but I can't retrace where in the code this problem exists. Upon removal of the combobox, the window works.

Comment: Which version of Ext is it? We don't use `new` operator or `SimpleStore` in the contemporary versions.